# Obfuscation in IBM MobileFirst 6.3

Tags: obfuscation, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to obfuscate javascript files in my worklight project. is it a good practice to obfuscate the javascript files in a worklight application?. is there a way to do obfuscation using Gulp in worklight application?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to obfuscate your application's JavaScript code - go ahead and obfuscate.

The following blog post details obfuscation instructions in Worklight-based applications (this includes MobileFirst Platform): [Obfuscating JavaScript code in Worklight applications](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/obfuscating_javascript_code?lang=en)

Comment: Great to hear. Please mark as resolved when you can.

Comment: Great resource, but actually YUI Compressor, closure and uglifyjs are not "obfuscators". They are minifiers and optimizers. If you want a good obfuscator, I recommend JScrambler. You can find a gulp API client here: https://github.com/jscrambler/gulp-jscrambler

Comment: Yes, I believe a cautionary note is mentioned in the blog post.